# Exporting Latex code snippets into HTML when using Emacs org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Hi I recently stumbled upon Emacs' org mode for taking notes and I am interested in using it. 
I wish to keep my notes in an org file and publish them in html for reading.

But I also wish to include Latex formulae into my notes.

So far I have been able to export plain text in my org file into HTML
and export latex notes in another org file into a latex pdf.

But Latex formulae are not displayed when I export my document to HTML. 
This is what I tried to get my Latex into HTML

```
    #+TITLE:     NOTES
    #+AUTHOR:    [Smiling Buddha]
    #+EMAIL:     xyz.notes@gmail.com
    #+DATE:      2013-08-22 Thu
    #+KEYWORDS: 
    #+LANGUAGE:  en
    #+OPTIONS:   H:3 num:t toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
    #+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:nil skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc
    #+INFOJS_OPT: view:nil toc:nil ltoc:t mouse:underline buttons:0 path:http://orgmode.org/org-info.js
    #+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
    #+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
    #+STARTUP: indent
    #+LaTeX: \usepackage{amsmath} 


   #+BEGIN_LaTeX 
    \sqrt{x}  = 4
    #+END_LaTeX
```

However the HTML document just displays the title of the document and
the authors name.

Latex formula $\sqrt{x}=4$ is not generated. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`org-mode` uses `MathJax` to typeset the `TeX` when exported to `html`. To that end, in your `org` file you should have something like `Hello world \(e^{-i\pi) = 1\)` which should be exported correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Dror's answer:

`#+BEGIN_LaTeX ... #+END_LaTeX` only applies when exporting to latex.  It allows for backend specific code when exporting (by the same concept `#+Begin_HTML ... #+END_HTML` does the same for HTML code.

The full set of environments that allow for LaTeX code to be generated on export can be found in the [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html).

> LaTeX fragments don't need any special marking at all. The following
>   snippets will be identified as LaTeX source code:
>
> - Environments of any kind. The only requirement is that the \begin and \end statements appear on a new line, at the beginning of the line or after whitespaces only.
> - Text within the usual LaTeX math delimiters. To avoid conflicts with currency specifications, single ‘$’ characters are only recognized as math delimiters if the enclosed text contains at most two line breaks, is directly attached to the ‘$’ characters with no whitespace in between, and if the closing ‘$’ is followed by whitespace, punctuation or a dash. For the other delimiters, there is no such restriction, so when in doubt, use ‘(...)’ as inline math delimiters.